# is namespace prefixes used in wsdl part of the web service contract

Tags: wsdl

we have some internal code that processes web service calls but assumes the namespace prefix is "sch" for a particular namespace defined in our wsdl.

Is the sch prefix part of the wsdl contract? Must all client calls use the sch prefix as defined in the wsdl for the specified namespace?

I would have thought that the namespace prefix can be anything in the client call as long as it matches to the correct namespace specified in the client call? I'm I right or wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would have thought that the namespace prefix can be anything in the
>   client call as long as it matches to the correct namespace specified
>   in the client call? I'm I right or wrong?

Yes your're right, the namespace prefix could be declared anything as long as it points to the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is the sch prefix part of the wsdl contract? Must all client calls use the sch prefix as defined in the wsdl for the specified namespace?
```

Atleast for the case of Java, Yes, all clients must use the "sch" prefix as defined in the wsdl.
In java javax.xml.soap class has SOAPFactory class which has a method createName which takes the prefix name as an argument with targetnamespace.
This method is used when client sends some input to the webservice. You can see the foolowing link: 
[SOAP Factory API](http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/xml/soap/javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory.html)

```
I would have thought that the namespace prefix can be anything in the client call as long as it matches to the correct namespace specified in the client call? I'm I right or wrong?
```

yes you are right.